# Working example of multiple permitopen options in authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I have a working key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` with a single `permitopen` option configured. I went to add an additional `permitopen` and it does not allow tunnels to the new server. The [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Tunnels) says:

> Multiple PermitOpen options may be applied to the same public key if
>   they are separated by commas and thus a key can allow multiple ports.

However, the documentation does not show any examples. Can someone provide a working example? I've tried both the following:

`permitopen="host-1:3389",permitopen="host-2:3389" ssh-rsa AAAAC...`

and

`permitopen="host-1:3389,host-2:3389" ssh-rsa AAAAC...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've gotten it to work. The first example above works.

`permitopen="host-1:3389",permitopen="host-2:3389" ssh-rsa AAAAC...`

In my case it was not working because the host name is **case-sensitive**.

I was using the following command to connect:

`ssh -f user@tunneler -L 10001:host-1:3389 -L 10002:HOST-2:3389 -N`

which failed due to the capitalization of the second hostname.

`ssh -f user@tunneler -L 10001:host-1:3389 -L 10002:host-2:3389 -N` worked.

It must match *exactly* what is in the `permitopen` option.